# AVAssetExportSession video duration cuts off and is incorrect

Tags: ios, xcode, video, avfoundation

i'm adding audio to the video and exporting as a video using `AVAssetExportSession`. My code is written such that the video should be of `60 seconds`, where as the exported video is only `45 seconds`. This issue happens only in `iOS6` device not in `iOS7` device.

I have put my export progress output below from which you can understand that it gets stopped abruptly at 0.75.

```
2014-08-21 10:37:32.209 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.680000

2014-08-21 10:37:32.309 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.690556

2014-08-21 10:37:32.409 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.701667

2014-08-21 10:37:32.509 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.712222

2014-08-21 10:37:32.609 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.723333

2014-08-21 10:37:32.709 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.734444

2014-08-21 10:37:32.809 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.745000

2014-08-21 10:37:32.908 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.750556

2014-08-21 10:37:33.009 videoFilter[245:907] progress 2 - 0.750556

2014-08-21 10:37:33.362 videoFilter[245:907] progress 3 - 0.750556

2014-08-21 10:37:33.408 videoFilter[245:907] progress 3 - 0.750556 so on......same value
```

`AVassetexportsession` status shows as `AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown`